# How to point url from Global file using URL routing 3.5 asp.net without parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, url-routing

How to point url from Global file using URL routing 3.5 asp.net without parameters?

For example:

```
var url = "subdomain";

if(url == "subdomain")
{
//Route to the specific url
}

if(url == "subdomain2")
{
//Route to the specific url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can try something like

```
Server.Transfer("yourpage.aspx");
```

or

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

To give a more detailed answer, we all need more details in you question.